# C++ Builder 11.1.5 Android project can't deploy

Tags: android, c++, deployment, c++builder

Using C++Builder 11.1.5, I can't get an Android Project to deploy properly.
It compiles and links OK, but when it starts to deploy, I keep getting copy errors as follows:

```
[Copy Warning] Could not copy "D:\CBuilder\RADXE8Projects\Android Projects\RACLP\Android\Debug\libRACLP.so" to ".\Android\Debug\RACLP\debug\libRACLP.so". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

[Copy Warning] Could not copy "D:\CBuilder\RADXE8Projects\Android Projects\RACLP\Android\Debug\libRACLP.so" to ".\Android\Debug\RACLP\debug\libRACLP.so". Beginning retry 2 in 1000ms. The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

[Copy Warning] Could not copy "D:\CBuilder\RADXE8Projects\Android Projects\RACLP\Android\Debug\libRACLP.so" to ".\Android\Debug\RACLP\debug\libRACLP.so". Beginning retry 3 in 1000ms. The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

[Copy Warning] Could not copy "D:\CBuilder\RADXE8Projects\Android Projects\RACLP\Android\Debug\libRACLP.so" to ".\Android\Debug\RACLP\debug\libRACLP.so". Beginning retry 4 in 1000ms. The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

[Copy Warning] Could not copy "D:\CBuilder\RADXE8Projects\Android Projects\RACLP\Android\Debug\libRACLP.so" to ".\Android\Debug\RACLP\debug\libRACLP.so". Beginning retry 5 in 1000ms. The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

[Copy Warning] Could not copy "D:\CBuilder\RADXE8Projects\Android Projects\RACLP\Android\Debug\libRACLP.so" to ".\Android\Debug\RACLP\debug\libRACLP.so". Beginning retry 6 in 1000ms. The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

[Copy Warning] Could not copy "D:\CBuilder\RADXE8Projects\Android Projects\RACLP\Android\Debug\libRACLP.so" to ".\Android\Debug\RACLP\debug\libRACLP.so". Beginning retry 7 in 1000ms. The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

[Copy Warning] Could not copy "D:\CBuilder\RADXE8Projects\Android Projects\RACLP\Android\Debug\libRACLP.so" to ".\Android\Debug\RACLP\debug\libRACLP.so". Beginning retry 8 in 1000ms. The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

[Copy Warning] Could not copy "D:\CBuilder\RADXE8Projects\Android Projects\RACLP\Android\Debug\libRACLP.so" to ".\Android\Debug\RACLP\debug\libRACLP.so". Beginning retry 9 in 1000ms. The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

[Copy Warning] Could not copy "D:\CBuilder\RADXE8Projects\Android Projects\RACLP\Android\Debug\libRACLP.so" to ".\Android\Debug\RACLP\debug\libRACLP.so". Beginning retry 10 in 1000ms. The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

[Copy Error] Could not copy "D:\CBuilder\RADXE8Projects\Android Projects\RACLP\Android\Debug\libRACLP.so" to ".\Android\Debug\RACLP\debug\libRACLP.so". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
[Copy Error] Unable to copy file "D:\CBuilder\RADXE8Projects\Android Projects\RACLP\Android\Debug\libRACLP.so" to ".\Android\Debug\RACLP\debug\libRACLP.so". The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:13.7
```

Comment: Well... Why didn't you post a few more of the same?

Comment: Either your project is misconfigured, or this is a bug that should be [reported to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: Sad thing is, I haven't touched this project for a few months now.  Also, all my Android projects produce the same error.  This is definitely something amiss in the compiler.

Comment: Remy,  would this have anything to do with the version of the Android SDK that is installed?  I have 25.5 installed.  Maybe I should upgrade it?

Comment: Remy,  I found out what was wrong.  Seems there is a windows update that fixes this problem.  I downloaded and installed the following windows update:  2022-11 Cumulative Update for Windows 11 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5020044).  Once installed, my android programs now deploy properly.